# sudo useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later (no lock files)

Tags: server, sudo, lock, passwd-file

When doing this on Ubuntu server 14.04:

```
camilstaps@localhost:~$ sudo useradd --home-dir /var/www/xxx.camilstaps.nl/ --no-create-home --root /var/www/xxx.camilstaps.nl/ --shell /bin/sh xxx
```

I'm getting the error:

```
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

I checked and tried the following (found the suggestions all over the internet):

- Obviously, I'm using sudo
- There exists a file /etc/.pwd.lock, but it is empty and removing it doesn't help
- There are no other *.lock files in the /etc directory
- The filesystem is not full (14G available on /)
- Rebooting the server doesn't remove the lock.

I'm stumped. How can I unlock /etc/passwd?

---

#### `df -ih` output

```
camilstaps@localhost:~$ df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        1,3M  228K  1,1M   18% /
none             125K     4  125K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             124K   404  123K    1% /dev
tmpfs            125K   386  124K    1% /run
none             125K     5  125K    1% /run/lock
none             125K     1  125K    1% /run/shm
none             125K     2  125K    1% /run/user
```

Comment: Have you tried `adduser` instead of `useradd`?

Comment: what are the permissions of /etc/passwd ? is your partition mounted ro ?

Comment: @heemayl that does work, however, adduser doesn't have the possibility to set a user's root directory. Is there a way to do adduser and then change the root directory?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `rw-r--r--` - what do you mean with your second question though?

Comment: He's asking if the root filesystem is mounted read-only. Check: `mount | grep ' / '`

Comment: @muru alright, thanks - the output: `/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)` - so I guess it's not, but when an error occurs it is? I can write other files in the /etc directory normally.

Comment: @CamilStaps: You can use `adduser` and then change the `/etc/passwd` entry manually to make the desired directory (using proper permissions) as the home directory for the user, although i have not checked it.

Comment: @heemayl thanks - how do I exactly edit /etc/passwd then? Because http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/ doesn't show where the root directory is stored. I tried `usermod`, but it says `user 'xxx' does not exist`...

Comment: @CamilStaps: I see. you are trying a `chroot` dir.

Comment: This sometimes can happen when your disk is full as well. What does `df -i` show with regards to inode usage on the `/` filesystem?

Comment: @AaronD thanks, I added the output of that comment to my question - looks good to me though, only 18% is in use. The whole disk is 20G.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `adduser` instead of `useradd`.
`adduser` also provides an interactive session to configure your Linux user and also creates the necessary `/home/username/` directory automatically.

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

By the way, there is no difference between `adduser` and `useradd`. They both serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://#%20rm%20%E2%80%93rf%20/etc/passwd.lock%20#%20rm%20%E2%80%93rf%20/etc/shadow.lock%20#%20rm%20%E2%80%93rf%20/etc/group.lock%20#%20rm%20%E2%80%93rf%20/etc/gshadow.lock) and this solves the problem

You need to remove all the four files and then try

```bsh
/etc/passwd.lock
/etc/shadow.lock
/etc/group.lock
/etc/gshadow.lock
```

Logging as the root user

```
$ sudo su
```

```
rm –rf /etc/passwd.lock
rm –rf /etc/shadow.lock
rm –rf /etc/group.lock
rm –rf /etc/gshadow.lock
```

Then try your command.

```
camilstaps@localhost:~$ sudo useradd --home-dir /var/www/xxx.camilstaps.nl/ --no-create-home --root /var/www/xxx.camilstaps.nl/ --shell /bin/sh xxx
```